# How to control the screen-orientation for a Android/iPhone web app

Tags: iphone, android, web-applications, mobile-website, screen-orientation

I am in the middle of creating a web app for smartphones, Android devices and iPhone's. But I was thinking that it would be better if the web app only allowed a portrait screen-orientation, so no matter which way the user is holding their phone it will always remain in portrait.

So basically what I want to know is how can I have the screen always remain in portrait for both Android and iPhone, using JavaScript, HTML Meta Tags, CSS, or PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the "size", "width", and sometimes the "orientation" properties of the window object.  Set an event listener to fire a javascript event when the "resize" event happens.

As far as I know, though, you can't actually *control* the rotation.

Here's a demo: (I posted it to my web page, http://douglassims.org/rotation.html)

```
<head>

  <script>

  function checkRotation() {document.getElementById('orientationlabel').innerHTML='Orientation: ' + window.orientation + ' Width: ' + screen.width + ' Height: '+screen.height;} 
  function load() {window.addEventListener('resize', checkRotation, false);}
  </script>

</head>

<body onload='load();'>
  <center>
  <h2 id=orientationlabel>Nothing yet</h2>

</body>
```